# Swipe-left-to-search (iOS paging model) in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

Are there examples of iPhone apps that use the "Swipe-left-to-search" paging model from the iOS homescreen?

This is the graphical representation of it: http://bit.ly/a21Tto

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If you just want examples of apps you should probably make this community wiki.

Comment: You'd be getting many more answers if your question is less general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any off the top of my head, but it's a good idea to think about why that model works on the iOS home screen.

The home screen is a list of pages, which are each a list of icons. Search is the "zeroth page" that can suck items from the following pages and from the applications represented by the icons on those pages.

That's why the search field in other iOS applications is usually at the top of a list — it's the "zeroth list item" and causes information to be displayed about the items that follow it.